# How do I get rid of errors in .bat file that aren't affecting outcome of the script?

Tags: excel, batch-file, command-line

I have an application calls the below command:

```
C:\Users\212340141>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\excel.exe" /e "C:
\My Programs\CPU Analysis\data\IOParse.xlsm" "-iodumplocation"C:\My Programs\CPU
Analysis\iodump\065901_iodump.txt""
```

When I run this command, it opens excel, passing in the `C:\My Programs\CPU Analysis\iodump\065901_iodump.txt` path as a parameter for the excel book to use in the macros it runs automatically.  The macros run correctly and the file is modified correctly, but I get the following errors when I run the command:

[image: First Error]

[image: Second Error]

[image: Third Error]

[image: Fourth Error]

**How can I get rid of the errors?**

## Answer

As mentioned in the accepted answer, excel was trying to open multiple files because of how I wrote the command.  The way I solved this is I created a text file to hold the path I was trying to pass into the macro.  The macro would open the text file and read the path to get the path it needed.  This is much cleaner and easier than trying to get the path from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Description of the startup switches for Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291288) lists and describes the optional switches which can be used on starting Excel. `/e` is listed on this page written by Microsoft. But `-iodumplocation` is definitely not a command line switch for Excel.

Using double quotes within a double quoted string is always a mistake on command line and the result is unpredictable as depending on code of command line parser, see answer on [Why double quotes should be always only at beginning and end of an argument string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24008269/3074564)

The command line used is obviously interpreted by Excel as

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\excel.exe" /e "C:\My Programs\CPU Analysis\data\IOParse.xlsm" "-iodumplocation" C:\My Programs\CPU Analysis\iodump\065901_iodump.txt""
```

which results in

1. `/e` ...  starting without displaying the startup screen and without the creation of a new workbook.
2. `C:\My Programs\CPU Analysis\data\IOParse.xlsm` ... opening this marco-enabled workbook file.
3. `-iodumplocation` ... the failed attempt to open a file with name `-iodumplocation.xlsx` in current working directory.
4. `C:\My` ... the failed attempt to open a file with name `My.xlsx` in root of drive C:.
5. `Programs\CPU` ... the failed attempt to open a file with name `CPU.xlsx` in subdirectory `Programs` of current working directory.
6. `Analysis\iodump\065901_iodump.txt""` ... the failed attempt to open a file with invalid name `065901_iodump.txt""` in subdirectory `Analysis\iodump` of current working directory.

I can't suggest a correct command line as I don't know what `-iodumplocation` should be.

Comment: Thank you for your insight!  See my updated question for what I ended up doing.