# Why does database query using sqlcmd produce just empty file while same query works in Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd

I have made recently a huge MSSQL script which was working until the server environment changed and some queries are not anymore allowed. So I had to make a .bat file which executes this query from command line.

I get no error or something else. I just get a file with no entry. But I receive a lot of entries if I use the code of the query in the Management Studio.

Does somebody see where is the mistake in my command line?

I inserted some new lines for reading the code better. Everything except command `PAUSE` is on one line in the batch file.

EDIT: I figured out that the problem is in the last `WHERE` clause in the `LIKE` operater. If I take out the `LIKE` operater it works. It has nothing todo with the % caracter. it is effective the `LIKE` operater. Does anybody know how to fix that?

```
sqlcmd -S connection\string -U user -P password -d dbName -s";" -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; 
SELECT [per_nummer] as EmployeeID, 
[per_id] as System_nr, 
[per_pid] as PID, 
[per_anrede] as Gender, 
[per_vname] as Vorname, 
[per_name] as Name, 
[per_telEx] as Telefon, 
[per_email] as Email, 
[per_instradierungHauptort] as Instradierung, 
[per_gebnr] as Gebaeudenummer, 
(SELECT mobileTelephoneNumber FROM [dbName].[dbo].[import_zuko_GLDAP_DUMP] WHERE UserID = per_pid ) as Mobile, 
[per_business_area] as Business_Area, 
(SELECT csgdivision FROM [dbName].[dbo].[import_zuko_GLDAP_DUMP] WHERE UserID = per_pid ) as Division,
NULL as Bereich, 
(SELECT csgCompany FROM [dbName].[dbo].[import_zuko_GLDAP_DUMP] WHERE UserID = per_pid ) as Firma,
[per_sprache] as Korespondenzsprache,
(SELECT roomnumber FROM [dbName].[dbo].[import_zuko_GLDAP_DUMP] WHERE UserID = per_pid ) as Bueronummer,
[per_floor] as Etage,
(SELECT convert(varchar, convert(date,[per_eintrittsdatum]), 104)) as Eintritt_per,
(SELECT convert(varchar, convert(date,[per_austrittsdatum]), 104)) as Austritt_per,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 104) AS letzte_mutation,
per_lm as Linemanager,
(SELECT TOP 1 per_pid FROM [dbName].[dbo].[person] WHERE per_nummer = master_table.per_lm) AS lm_pid,
(SELECT convert(varchar, convert(date,[per_lm_von]), 104)) as lm_von,
(SELECT convert(varchar, convert(date,[per_lm_bis]), 104)) as lm_bis,
NULL FROM [dbName].[dbo].[person] as master_table
WHERE
[per_nummer] IS NOT NULL AND per_pidStatus = 'A' AND
([per_pid] LIKE('A%')OR [per_pid] LIKE('F%')OR [per_pid] LIKE('W%'))"
-w 1000 -W  -o "\\servername\G$\path\to\file.csv"
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Different default options

Do you have read carefully [sqlcmd Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) documentation by Microsoft?

There is at top the **important** information:

> Because different default options may apply, you might see different behavior when you execute the same query in SQL Server Management Studio in SQLCMD Mode and in the **sqlcmd** utility.

Therefore the empty file could be caused by different default options.

### Space between option and value of option

Further the documentation contains at top:

> Currently, **sqlcmd** does not require a space between the command line option and the value. However, in a future release, a space may be required between the command line option and the value.

Double quotes inside an argument string are often problematic, see answer on [Why double quotes should be always only at beginning and end of an argument string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24008269/3074564)

Therefore I suggest to follow the advice of Microsoft and change `-s";"` to `-s ";"` with a space charcter after `-s` as done for all other options, too.

### Escaping percentage sign

Do you have tried to escape each `%` in the query string with an additional `%` and using therefore 3 times `%%` in the query string?

Command line interpreter `cmd.exe` could interpret the string between two `%` as a reference to an environment variable and as there is no such environment variable, removes everything between two `%` from the command line.

**Update:** It turned out that indeed the not escaped percentage signs resulted in a wrong query string and therefore in an empty results file.

### Command with path and extension

General hint:
It is always advisable to specify in batch files commands like **sqlcmd** with full name which means with path and file extension as this makes the execution of the application independent on the values of the environment variables **PATH** and **PATHEXT**.

Comment: Thank you Mofi for your answer. I made all changes and I was reading the documentation carefully. nothing changed at the situation. after that I moved step by step trought the code. The problem is actually the LIKE operator in the WHERE clause. So if I say where per_pid = 'abcdefg' it works but when I change it to WHERE per_pid LIKE('abcdegf') it doesn't work even with %. Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: That was the point the double <code>%%</code>. thank you Mofi for the grat help