# How to set environment variables with spaces?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, windows-7

I need to set values to a environmental variable using a batch file. I wrote the script for this:

```
@echo off
set value="Hello world"
setx -M srijani "%srijani%;%value%"
```

It gives the error:

```
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s).
Type "SETX /?" for usage.
```

I googled and found that while using white spaces we need to write it inside a double quotes.

```
set value="Hello world"
```

But, that is not working too.

Note: I am on Windows 7.

Comment: Standard mistake often made is using `set variable="value"` instead of `set "variable=value"`. See for example [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386697) for an explanation of the difference on where first quote is specified on line with command __SET__.

Comment: @Mofi - that's the answer in fact...

Comment: A great advantage of Mofi's suggestion is, that `set "variable=value"` does _not_ include the surrounding quotes in the value, so you need to care about them _only_ when expanding (reading) the value like `"%variable%"`, so any code becomes more consistent in terms of quotation...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The error output by command **setx** is caused by wrong usage of the quotes on assigning the string to variable `value`.

The command is **set** and the parameter is `variable=value`. As for most commands and applications it is possible and often required to surround a parameter with double quotes if containing 1 or more spaces or any other character from this list: `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``. Those characters are displayed on last help page output by running in a command prompt window `cmd /?` or `help cmd`.

But wrong is here:

```
set value="Hello world"
```

With first double quote after the equal sign the entire parameter `variable=value` of command **set** is not enclosed in double quotes.

This results in interpreting the double quotes as part of the string to assign to variable with name `value`. Everything from the equal sign to end of line including the double quotes and possibly existing trailing spaces and horizontal tabs is assigned here to variable `value` instead of just the string `Hello world` as expected.

On expanding the line

```
setx -M srijani "%srijani%;%value%"
```

the result is therefore:

```
setx -M srijani "Value of variable srijani;"Hello world""
```

And command **setx** interprets the wrong quoted parameter as syntax error.

Correct would be using:

```
set "value=Hello world"
```

Now the entire parameter of command **set** is enclosed in double quotes. Therefore ignored on parsing the line are:

- all spaces/tabs between command **set** and the first double quote,
- the first double quote,
- the last double quote,
- and all perhaps existing spaces/tabs after last double quote.

So just `Hello world` is assigned to a variable with name `value`.

For more details about correct assignment of a string to an environment variable read answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) It contains also a simple demo batch code.

Some more information:

How an argument string containing 1 or more quotes somewhere in the middle is interpreted depends on command respectively application. The behavior on interpreting an argument with 1 or more `"` within an argument string can vary depending on used compiler as explained in an answer on [batch file: list rar file in specific folder and write result into text file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24008269/3074564) and of course the source code of the command / application.

For most commands and applications the correct syntax is:

```
command "parameter in quotes"
"Path to application\app.exe" "parameter in quotes"
```

But there are applications which require quotes in the middle of an argument string. An example of such an application is *Windows Explorer*.

The following syntax is required to open an *Explorer* window from within a batch file with current directory displayed in window.

```
explorer.exe /e,"%CD%"
```

Not working are:

```
explorer.exe "/e,%CD%"
explorer.exe /e "%CD%"
```

So `explorer.exe` requires that the directory to open is specified after `/e,` with quotes in the middle of parameter string or it interprets `"/e,%CD%"` respectively `"/e %CD%"` as name of the directory with path to display in *Explorer* window.

See also [SS64 - Windows Explorer command-line options](https://ss64.com/nt/explorer.html).

Answer (score 2):

setx foo "\"this env var has spaces and double quotes at each end\""