# Batch script issue with IFs?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have this script but for some reason I keep getting issues. One of the issues was something about the syntax being incorrect. I re-ran it and the issue is different but it says "N was unexpected at this time" then it has the line "if   EQU N (" where it broke.

Here is the script:

```
SET LOG_FILE="D:\SmCpm\ElektronTMS\%PCN_NUM%_RollbackLog.txt"
SET UNINSTALL5012=N
SET UNINSTALL5013=N
SET UNINSTALL5014=N
SET UNINSTALL5015=N
SET UNINSTALL5017=N
SET UNINSTALL5018=N
SET UNINSTALLV131=N
SET UNINSTALLV140=N
SET UNINSTALLV141=N
SET INST=""
SET ETMSFILENAME="ElektronTMS.msi"

:: *******************************************
:: Stop the SMF Service.

ECHO Rolling back installation of %PCN_NUM%

net stop smf
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > nul



:: *******************************************
:: determine which PCNs need to be uninstalled.

FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Reuters\TMS" /v PCN5021') DO (

    set INST=%%B
)

if not x%INST:5012=%==x%INST% (
    SET UNINSTALL5012=Y
)
if not x%INST:5013=%==x%INST% (
    SET UNINSTALL5013=Y
)
if not x%INST:5014=%==x%INST% (
    SET UNINSTALL5014=Y
)
if not x%INST:5015=%==x%INST% (
    SET UNINSTALL5015=Y
)
if not x%INST:5017=%==x%INST% (
    SET UNINSTALL5017=Y
)
if not x%INST:5018=%==x%INST% (
    SET UNINSTALL5018=Y
)
if not x%INST:V131=%==x%INST% (
    SET UNINSTALLV131=Y
)
if not x%INST:V140=%==x%INST% (
    SET UNINSTALLV140=Y
)
if not x%INST:V141=%==x%INST% (
    SET UNINSTALLV141=Y
)


:: ***********************
:: Uninstall the packages.

ECHO Rolling back patch

IF %UNINSTALLV131% EQU Y (
    FOR /F "tokens=3*" %%C IN ('c:\windows\system32\reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\48AB8A7CAE88C33488B5F1498871520C\InstallProperties /v LocalPackage') DO (
        SET LOCALPACKAGE=%%C
    )

    FOR /F "tokens=3*" %%S IN ('c:\windows\system32\reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\48AB8A7CAE88C33488B5F1498871520C\InstallProperties /v InstallSource') DO (
        SET SOURCEINSTALL=%%S
    )

    if not exist %SOURCEINSTALL% (
        md "%SOURCEINSTALL%"
        SET SOURCEEXISTS=N
    )

    if exist %SOURCEINSTALL% (
        SET SOURCEEXISTS=Y
    )
    SET COPYTODIR=%SOURCEINSTALL%%ETMSFILENAME%

    copy /y %LOCALPACKAGE% %COPYTODIR%

    msiexec -package {C7A8BA84-88EA-433C-885B-1F94881725C0} -uninstall {F732939E-ED57-43FC-B298-83F933E1F950} -quiet -norestart -lv+ %LOG_FILE%
    ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > nul

    if %SOURCEEXISTS% EQU N (
        rd /s /q "%SOURCEINSTALL%"
    ) else (
        del /F %COPYTODIR%
    )
)
IF %UNINSTALLV140% EQU Y (
    FOR /F "tokens=3*" %%C IN ('c:\windows\system32\reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\98AF25D0FB734FC4BA465843970476B6\InstallProperties /v LocalPackage') DO (
        SET LOCALPACKAGE=%%C
    )

    FOR /F "tokens=3*" %%S IN ('c:\windows\system32\reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\98AF25D0FB734FC4BA465843970476B6\InstallProperties /v InstallSource') DO (
        SET SOURCEINSTALL=%%S
    )   
    if not exist %SOURCEINSTALL% (
        md "%SOURCEINSTALL%"
        SET SOURCEEXISTS=N
    )

    if exist %SOURCEINSTALL% (
        SET SOURCEEXISTS=Y
    )
    SET COPYTODIR=%SOURCEINSTALL%%ETMSFILENAME%

    copy /y %LOCALPACKAGE% %COPYTODIR%

    msiexec -package {0D52FA89-37BF-4CF4-AB64-85347940676B} -uninstall {C845F8AE-6935-42D9-AE8C-2564E2A82C71} -quiet -norestart -lv+ %LOG_FILE%
    ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > nul

    if %SOURCEEXISTS% EQU N (
        rd /s /q "%SOURCEINSTALL%"
    ) else (
        del /F %COPYTODIR%
    )
)
IF %UNINSTALLV141% EQU Y (
    FOR /F "tokens=3*" %%C IN ('c:\windows\system32\reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\DFFF30F7568D1D144B5B7B785F32638D\InstallProperties /v LocalPackage') DO (
        SET LOCALPACKAGE=%%C
    )

    echo %LOCALPACKAGE%

    FOR /F "tokens=3*" %%S IN ('c:\windows\system32\reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\DFFF30F7568D1D144B5B7B785F32638D\InstallProperties /v InstallSource') DO (
        SET SOURCEINSTALL=%%S
    )   

    if not exist %SOURCEINSTALL% (
        md "%SOURCEINSTALL%"
        SET SOURCEEXISTS=N
    )

    if exist %SOURCEINSTALL% (
        SET SOURCEEXISTS=Y
    )
    SET COPYTODIR=%SOURCEINSTALL%%ETMSFILENAME%

    copy /y %LOCALPACKAGE% %COPYTODIR%

    msiexec -package {7F03FFFD-D865-41D1-B4B5-B787F52336D8} -uninstall {464FBA62-6FA9-4744-BDA7-68284B61B6DB} -quiet -norestart -lv+ %LOG_FILE%
    ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > nul       

    if %SOURCEEXISTS% EQU Y (
        rd /s /q "%SOURCEINSTALL%"
    ) else (
        del /F %COPYTODIR%
    )
)
```

I have queried all registry value details and i can see that there is a source install value and a local package value as well. At first it complained about the syntax error being with my "if not exist" but now i get another error and i don't know what is wrong with my batch!

Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: seems, you are not aware of [delayed expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082).

Comment: Hi Stephen. Should i use ! instead of % for all of my variables then? Or are there some I can use % for?

Comment: Use `!var!` for the variables you intend to be able to change (and test for changes) from within the script.  You should also have `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`

Comment: You should also use `equ` for numeric comparisons, and `==` for string comparison. Note that it's also better to use `"%var%"=="somestring"` with double quotes, else string with spaces will brake your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided batch code can be simplified by using a subroutine which also avoids the need of using delayed expansion.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "LOG_FILE=D:\SmCpm\ElektronTMS\%PCN_NUM%_RollbackLog.txt"
SET "UNINSTALL5012=N"
SET "UNINSTALL5013=N"
SET "UNINSTALL5014=N"
SET "UNINSTALL5015=N"
SET "UNINSTALL5017=N"
SET "UNINSTALL5018=N"
SET "UNINSTALLV131=N"
SET "UNINSTALLV140=N"
SET "UNINSTALLV141=N"
SET "INST=x"
SET "ETMSFILENAME=ElektronTMS.msi"

:: *******************************************
:: Stop the SMF Service.

ECHO Rolling back installation of %PCN_NUM%

%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe stop smf
REM %SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > nul


:: *******************************************
:: determine which PCNs need to be uninstalled.

FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Reuters\TMS" /v PCN5021 2^>nul') DO SET "INST=%%B"

IF NOT "%INST:5012=%" == "%INST%" SET "UNINSTALL5012=Y"
IF NOT "%INST:5013=%" == "%INST%" SET "UNINSTALL5013=Y"
IF NOT "%INST:5014=%" == "%INST%" SET "UNINSTALL5014=Y"
IF NOT "%INST:5015=%" == "%INST%" SET "UNINSTALL5015=Y"
IF NOT "%INST:5017=%" == "%INST%" SET "UNINSTALL5017=Y"
IF NOT "%INST:5018=%" == "%INST%" SET "UNINSTALL5018=Y"
IF NOT "%INST:5019=%" == "%INST%" SET "UNINSTALL5019=Y"
IF NOT "%INST:V131=%" == "%INST%" SET "UNINSTALLV131=Y"
IF NOT "%INST:V140=%" == "%INST%" SET "UNINSTALLV140=Y"
IF NOT "%INST:V141=%" == "%INST%" SET "UNINSTALLV141=Y"


:: ***********************
:: Uninstall the packages.

ECHO Rolling back patch

IF %UNINSTALLV131% == Y CALL :UnInstallPatch "48AB8A7CAE88C33488B5F1498871520C" "C7A8BA84-88EA-433C-885B-1F94881725C0" "F732939E-ED57-43FC-B298-83F933E1F950"
IF %UNINSTALLV140% == Y CALL :UnInstallPatch "98AF25D0FB734FC4BA465843970476B6" "0D52FA89-37BF-4CF4-AB64-85347940676B" "C845F8AE-6935-42D9-AE8C-2564E2A82C71"
IF %UNINSTALLV141% == Y CALL :UnInstallPatch "DFFF30F7568D1D144B5B7B785F32638D" "7F03FFFD-D865-41D1-B4B5-B787F52336D8" "464FBA62-6FA9-4744-BDA7-68284B61B6DB"

ENDLOCAL
GOTO :EOF


:: *********************************
:: Subfunction to uninstall a patch.

:UnInstallPatch
set "ProductID=%~1"
set "PackageID=%~2"
set "UninstallID=%~3"

FOR /F "tokens=3*" %%C IN ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\%ProductID%\InstallProperties /v LocalPackage') DO SET "LOCALPACKAGE=%%~C"
FOR /F "tokens=3*" %%S IN ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\%ProductID%\InstallProperties /v InstallSource') DO  SET "SOURCEINSTALL=%%~S"

MD "%SOURCEINSTALL%" 2>nul
IF EXIST "%SOURCEINSTALL%" ( SET "SOURCEEXISTS=Y" ) ELSE ( SET "SOURCEEXISTS=N" )

SET "COPYTODIR=%SOURCEINSTALL%%ETMSFILENAME%"

COPY /Y "%LOCALPACKAGE%" "%COPYTODIR%"

START "" /WAIT %SystemRoot%\System32\msiexec.exe -package {%PackageID%} -uninstall {%UninstallID%} -quiet -norestart -lv+ "%LOG_FILE%"
REM %SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > nul

IF %SOURCEEXISTS% == Y (
    RD /S /Q "%SOURCEINSTALL%"
) ELSE (
    DEL /F "%COPYTODIR%"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Take also a look on answer on [set environment variables with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564) for the reason of using

```
set "variable=value"
```

instead of

```
set variable=value
```

or

```
set variable="value"
```

Well, variable `LOG_FILE` with quotes included was set and used correct, but not variable `ETMSFILENAME` with quotes included and concatenated with value of variable `SOURCEINSTALL`.

I think none of the **ping** executions to wait 5 seconds is really necessary before processing continues which is the reason for commenting them out. But this was not verified by me.

Comment: Thanks for that. This looks awesome - i'll give it a study-through!