# Why can't get password protected folder program to work in batch?

Tags: variables, batch-file, passwords

I'm trying to create a batch file that checks if

- the directory `C:\Pswrd.Zask`,
- the user name file `C:\Pswrd.Zask\Username.Zask`,
- and the password file `C:\Pswrd.Zask\Password.Zask`

all exist.

The batch processing should continue on `PasswordScreen` if the two files in the directory exist.

But batch processing should continue on `CreatePasswordScreen` if they don't exist all.

The create `CreatePasswordScreen` block asks for user input. That input is then stored into a file named `Password.Zask` & `Username.Zask` inside the folder `C:\Pswrd.Zask`.

On second run of the program, the program checks existence of that folder, the user name file and the password file, and then sets the user name & password from the two files in `C:\Pswrd.Zask` to variables right before the `PasswordScreen` block which will be used to determine if the password is correct or not.

The problem is that I cannot get the password and user name to store correctly in the batch file as a variable without the batch process ultimately coming to a end for an unknown reason.

Did I miss use a command?

The problem should be right under then line that says `:UsernameExist`.

```
@echo off
color 0a

if not exist "C:\Pswrd.Zask\" (
mkdir "C:\Pswrd.Zask\"
if "!errorlevel!" EQU "0" (
  goto DirectoryExist
) else (
echo Created the folder "C:\Pswrd.Zask" 
)    
) else (
  goto DirectoryExist
)

:DirectoryExist

if exist C:\Pswrd.Zask\Password.Zask (
goto PasswordExist
) else (
goto CreatePasswordScreen
)
:PasswordExist

if exist C:\Pswrd.Zask\Username.Zask (
goto UsernameExist
) else (
goto CreatePasswordScreen
)

:UsernameExist

for /f "Delims=" %%A in (C:\Pswrd.Zask\Password.Zask) do (
  set CHECKPASSWORD=%%A

for /f "Delims=" %%B in (C:\Pswrd.Zask\Username.Zask) do (
  set CHECKUSERNAME=%%B 

goto PasswordScreen

:CreatePasswordScreen
cls
echo Create a password.
echo.

set /p "CREATEPASSWORD= Enter password : "
set /p "CREATEUSERNAME= Enter username : "

echo %CREATEPASSWORD% >> C:\Pswrd.Zask\Password.Zask
attrib C:\Pswrd.Zask\Password.Zask -s -h & echo Password Created!

echo %CREATEUSERNAME% >> C:\Pswrd.Zask\Username.Zask
attrib C:\Pswrd.Zask\Username.Zask -s -h & echo Username Created!

echo.
echo Loading...
timeout /5

:PasswordScreen
color 0a
cls
echo Existing User Account.
echo.
set /p "PASSWORD= Enter Password : "
set /p "USERNAME= Enter Username : "
if %PASSWORD%==%CHECKPASSWORD% goto Operation1True
if not %PASSWORD%==%CHECKPASSWORD% goto OperationFalse
:Operation1True
if %PASSWORD%==%CHECKPASSWORD% goto Operation2True
if not %PASSWORD%==%CHECKPASSWORD% goto OperationFalse

:OperationFalse
color 0c
echo Password Incorrect!
timeout /10
goto PasswordScreen

:Operation2True
cls
echo Password Correct!
pause
```

I figured out the solution, i chanced it to the following.

```
@echo off
color 0a

if not exist "C:\Pswrd.Zask\" (
mkdir "C:\Pswrd.Zask\"
if "!errorlevel!" EQU "0" (
goto DirectoryExist
) else (
echo Created the folder "C:\Pswrd.Zask" & timeout /t 5 
)
) else (
goto DirectoryExist
)

:DirectoryExist

if exist C:\Pswrd.Zask\Password.Zask (
goto PasswordExist
) else (
goto CreatePasswordScreen
)
:PasswordExist

if exist C:\Pswrd.Zask\Username.Zask (
goto UsernameExist
) else (
goto CreatePasswordScreen
)


:UsernameExist

for /f "Delims=" %%A in (C:\Pswrd.Zask\Password.Zask) do (
set CHECKPASSWORD=%%A
)
for /f "Delims=" %%B in (C:\Pswrd.Zask\Username.Zask) do (
set CHECKUSERNAME=%%B
)

goto PasswordScreen

:CreatePasswordScreen
cls
echo Create a password.
echo.

set /p "CREATEPASSWORD= Enter password : "
set /p "CREATEUSERNAME= Enter username : "

echo %CREATEPASSWORD% >> C:\Pswrd.Zask\Password.Zask
attrib C:\Pswrd.Zask\Password.Zask +s +h & echo Password Created!

echo %CREATEUSERNAME% >> C:\Pswrd.Zask\Username.Zask
attrib C:\Pswrd.Zask\Username.Zask +s +h & echo Username Created!


start %~n0%~x0
exit
:PasswordScreen
color 0a
cls
echo Existing User Account.
echo.
set /p "PASSWORD= Enter Password : "
set /p "USERNAME= Enter Username : "

if %PASSWORD%==%CHECKPASSWORD% (
goto Operation1True
) else (
goto OperationFalse
)

:Operation1True
if %USERNAME%==%CHECKUSERNAME% (
goto Operation2True
) else (
goto OperationFalse
)

:OperationFalse
color 0c
echo Password Incorrect!
timeout /t 10
goto PasswordScreen

:Operation2True
cls
echo Password Correct!
echo.
pause
```

Comment: Your `set /p` lines are not correct.  Use `set /p PASSWORD="Enter Password : "` (note where the double quotes are)

Comment: @KoryGill - that's a perfectly valid way of using `set /p`. It preserves spaces without including quotes in the variable value.

Comment: hmm...learn something new every day.  the usage you mention is valid, but i do not understand the use case you mention, nor can i repro it when i tried. don't want to take these comments off-topic, so no reply needed.

Comment: @KoryGill See [set environment variables with spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564) and [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) to learn why `set "variable=value"` is nearly always better than `set variable="value"` although for `set /p` it is not so important because string after first equal sign is always interpreted as prompt text and not as value to assign to the variable and `cmd.exe` removes the double quotes in this special case from prompt text.

Comment: Thanks for pointer @Mofi.

Comment: @zask Look on the two __for__ loops below label `UsernameExist`. They have both an opening `(` but no closing `)` and this results in a syntax error on parsing the body block of the __for__ loops. As both __for__ loops have only 1 command in body, you can also use `for /F "delims=" %%A in (C:\Pswrd.Zask\Password.Zask) do set "CHECKPASSWORD=%%A"` - single command on same line after `do` without parenthesis.