# set /a in If statement condition unable to work

Tags: batch-file

Below are my simple calculator batch i trying to do, however on the set /a unable to do the job. What is the problem and my mistake?

```
@echo off
Title Calculator
:start
echo Press 1 for "+"
echo Press 2 for Exit
echo.
set /p input="Please choose your option: "
if %input%==1 (
echo.
set /p num1="Please enter first number: "
set /p num2="Please enter second number: "
set /a ans=%num1%+%num2%
echo Your answer is %ans%
pause
cls
goto start
)
if %input%==2 (
echo.
echo Thanks!
pause
exit
) else echo Invalid input!
pause
goto start
```

When i first run the batch is will return me the Missing operand. When i continue again the error disappear without giving me the answer, when the third time i continue, it return me the answer of the number that i wanted to add up.

For example:
1. 10+10 result is Missing operand
2. 1+1 result is empty
3. 2+2 result is 20 (which is the 2 number i enter at first time)

Please help what my error is. Thanks.

Comment: Indent the lines within parenthetical code blocks. You don't have to left-justify everything in batch scripts. Anyway, you need delayed expansion when retrieving a variable in the same loop or code block in which it was set.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your batch code with using delayed expansion and indents as wisely suggested by [rojo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1683264/rojo):

```
@echo off
title Calculator
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
:Begin
echo Press 1 for "+"
echo Press 2 for Exit
echo/
set "input="
set /P "input=Please choose your option: "
if "!input!"=="1" (
    echo/
    set /P "num1=Please enter first number: "
    set /P "num2=Please enter second number: "
    set /A ans=num1+num2
    echo Your answer is !ans!
    pause
    cls
    goto Begin
)
if "!input!"=="2" (
    echo/
    echo Thanks^^!
    echo/
    pause
    exit /B
)
echo Invalid input^^!
echo/
pause
echo/
goto Begin
```

Variable `input` is always cleared before user is asked because otherwise the user could just hit key <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to keep current value of variable `input`.

Delayed expansion is used on checking user input against `1` or `2` in case of user enters a character which would result in a syntax error on execution with not using delayed expansion. Better would be nevertheless the usage of command `choice` for first user prompt.

For an expression evaluated on runtime by using `set /A` the environment variables can be specified directly without being expanded at all. So instead of using

```
set /A ans=%num1%+%num2%
```

or

```
set /A ans=!num1!+!num2!
```

it is enough to write

```
set /A ans=num1+num2
```

because with parameter `/A` command `set` interprets `num1` and `num2` automatically as names of variables.

Delayed expansion is nevertheless needed to print the result value stored in variable `ans` because command processor expands otherwise `%ans%` by nothing respectively the value of previous run on parsing the entire block starting with `(` and ending with `)`. This can be seen on running your batch file from within a command prompt window with first line changed to `@echo on` for debugging.

For more details run in a command prompt window `set /?` or `help set` and read the output help pages.

**start** is the name of a command. Therefore it is not good to use this word as name of a label although possible.

By the way: Always use `set "variable=value"` and never `set variable="value"` as this makes a big difference, see the answers on

- [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)
- [How to set environment variables with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564)