# How do I put a space in a batch file if statement?

Tags: batch-file, command

So, (a snippet of) my code is:

```
@echo off
set /p input=" "
if %input% == start_internal /DEV goto internal_dev
:internal_dev
::Some stuff here::
```

and every time I try it, it exists, and I am wondering how I can add the space in `start_internal /DEV` if at all possible. Thanks

P.S. It should work in Windows 10 too.

Comment: Use double quotes.  `if /I "%input%"=="start_internal /DEV"`.  The `/I` switch makes a case-insensitive comparison.

Comment: And read additionally [How to set environment variables with spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564) and [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) as you use the double quotes not right on lines with command __set__.

Comment: Dear rojo, now when I do it, it is saying `goto was unexpected at this time`.  What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Easy, use quotes " text here... ". Heres the fixed code if your lazy xd.

```
set /p input=" "
if "%input%" == "start internal" :: do stuff
:: do stuff
```