# Conversion from unix bash script to windows batch script

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file

I'm trying to convert a Linux bash script to its windows counter part.
This is the actual bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage parse_log.sh caffe.log
# It creates the following two text files, each containing a table:
#     caffe.log.test (columns: '#Iters Seconds TestAccuracy TestLoss')
#     caffe.log.train (columns: '#Iters Seconds TrainingLoss LearningRate')


# get the dirname of the script
DIR="$( cd "$(dirname "$0")" ; pwd -P )"

if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]
then
echo "Usage parse_log.sh /path/to/your.log"
exit
fi
LOG=`basename $1`
sed -n '/Iteration .* Testing net/,/Iteration *. loss/p' $1 > aux.txt
sed -i '/Waiting for data/d' aux.txt
sed -i '/prefetch queue empty/d' aux.txt
sed -i '/Iteration .* loss/d' aux.txt
sed -i '/Iteration .* lr/d' aux.txt
sed -i '/Train net/d' aux.txt
grep 'Iteration ' aux.txt | sed  's/.*Iteration \([[:digit:]]*\).*/\1/g' > aux0.txt
grep 'Test net output #0' aux.txt | awk '{print $11}' > aux1.txt
grep 'Test net output #1' aux.txt | awk '{print $11}' > aux2.txt

# Extracting elapsed seconds
# For extraction of time since this line contains the start time
grep '] Solving ' $1 > aux3.txt
grep 'Testing net' $1 >> aux3.txt
$DIR/extract_seconds.py aux3.txt aux4.txt

# Generating
echo '#Iters Seconds TestAccuracy TestLoss'> $LOG.test
paste aux0.txt aux4.txt aux1.txt aux2.txt | column -t >> $LOG.test
rm aux.txt aux0.txt aux1.txt aux2.txt aux3.txt aux4.txt

# For extraction of time since this line contains the start time
grep '] Solving ' $1 > aux.txt
grep ', loss = ' $1 >> aux.txt
grep 'Iteration ' aux.txt | sed  's/.*Iteration \([[:digit:]]*\).*/\1/g' > aux0.txt
grep ', loss = ' $1 | awk '{print $9}' > aux1.txt
grep ', lr = ' $1 | awk '{print $9}' > aux2.txt

# Extracting elapsed seconds
$DIR/extract_seconds.py aux.txt aux3.txt

# Generating
echo '#Iters Seconds TrainingLoss LearningRate'> $LOG.train
paste aux0.txt aux3.txt aux1.txt aux2.txt | column -t >> $LOG.train
rm aux.txt aux0.txt aux1.txt aux2.txt  aux3.txt
```

And this is my converted version:

```
ECHO OFF
REM Usage parse_log.sh caffe.log
REM It creates the following two text files, each containing a table:
REM     caffe.log.test (columns: '#Iters Seconds TestAccuracy TestLoss')
REM     caffe.log.train (columns: '#Iters Seconds TrainingLoss LearningRate')

SET sed="tools/3rdparty/bin/sed.exe"
SET awk="tools/3rdparty/bin/awk.exe"
SET grep="tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe"
SET rm="tools/3rdparty/bin/rm.exe"
SET paste="tools/3rdparty/bin/paste.exe"

REM get the dirname of the script
SET DIR=%~dp0

IF [%1]==[] (
ECHO "Usage parse_log.bat path\to\your.log"
EXIT
)

SET LOG="basename %~n1"
ECHO "Dir = %DIR%"
ECHO "LOG = %LOG%"

%sed% -n "/Iteration .* Testing net/,/Iteration *. loss/p" %1 > aux.txt
%sed% -i "/Waiting for data/d" aux.txt
%sed% -i "/prefetch queue empty/d" aux.txt
%sed% -i "/Iteration .* loss/d" aux.txt
%sed% -i "/Iteration .* lr/d" aux.txt
%sed% -i "/Train net/d" aux.txt
%grep% "Iteration " aux.txt | %sed%  "s/.*Iteration \([[:digit:]]*\).*/\1/g" > aux0.txt
%grep% "Test net output #0" aux.txt | %awk% "{print %11}" > aux1.txt
%grep% "Test net output #1" aux.txt | %awk% "{print %11}" > aux2.txt

REM Extracting elapsed seconds
REM For extraction of time since this line contains the start time
%grep% "] Solving " %1 > aux3.txt
%grep% "Testing net" %1 >> aux3.txt
%DIR%/extract_seconds.py aux3.txt aux4.txt

REM Generating
ECHO "#Iters Seconds TestAccuracy TestLoss"> %LOG%.test
%paste% aux0.txt aux4.txt aux1.txt aux2.txt | column -t >> %LOG%.test
%rm% aux.txt aux0.txt aux1.txt aux2.txt aux3.txt aux4.txt

REM For extraction of time since this line contains the start time
%grep% "] Solving " %1 > aux.txt
%grep% ", loss = " %1 >> aux.txt
%grep% "Iteration " aux.txt | %sed%  "s/.*Iteration \([[:digit:]]*\).*/\1/g" > aux0.txt
%grep% ", loss = " %1 | %awk% "{print %9}" > aux1.txt
%grep% ", lr = " %1 | %awk% "{print %9}" > aux2.txt

REM Extracting elapsed seconds
%DIR%/extract_seconds.py aux.txt aux3.txt

REM Generating
ECHO "#Iters Seconds TrainingLoss LearningRate"> %LOG%.train
%paste% aux0.txt aux3.txt aux1.txt aux2.txt | column -t >> %LOG%.train
%rm% aux.txt aux0.txt aux1.txt aux2.txt  aux3.txt
```

The problem is first of all I don't know if this is the correct conversion and does exactly what the bash script does. And second of all when I run the script, the cursor starts blinking (waiting) when it reaches the 
`ECHO "LOG = %LOG%"` section and after a long time, it prints the following:

```
tools/3rdparty/bin/sed.exe: couldn't edit aux.txt: is a terminal
tools/3rdparty/bin/sed.exe: couldn't edit aux.txt: is a terminal
tools/3rdparty/bin/sed.exe: couldn't edit aux.txt: is a terminal
tools/3rdparty/bin/sed.exe: couldn't edit aux.txt: is a terminal
tools/3rdparty/bin/sed.exe: couldn't edit aux.txt: is a terminal
```

And it waits again!

What is wrong here?

---

### UPDATE

After changing `aux.txt` to `auxx.txt` the first error is resolved. But now I get these errors:

```
awk: {print examples\cifar10\caffe.log1}
awk:                ^ backslash not last character on line
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
awk: {print examples\cifar10\caffe.log1}
awk:                ^ backslash not last character on line
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe: writing output: Invalid argument
Usage: ./extract_seconds input_file output_file
'column' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 2):

`AUX` is reserved word, see [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Do not use the following reserved names for the name of a file:
>
> CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8,
>   COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9. Also
>   avoid these names followed immediately by an extension; for example,
>   `NUL.txt` is not recommended. For more information, see [Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#namespaces).

Use another different name instead, e.g `auxx.txt`.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the first problem, now I get some other errors, I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Please read answers on [How to set environment variables with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564) and [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) as you most likely don't know how to define variable values with spaces correct.

Don't use `IF [%1]==[]` as square brackets have no special meaning in Windows command scripts on **IF** and therefore the batch processing could exit because of a syntax error with left value containing 1 or more spaces. Use instead `IF "%~1"==""` and execute in a command prompt window `call /?` for an explanation of `%~1` (first argument with surrounding double quotes removed).

It is advisable to use always `%~1`, `%~2`, ... with explicitly embedding those argument references in double quotes.

On Windows the directory separator is the backslash `\` character and not the forward slash `/` character. Windows command processor corrects this often made mistake automatically where it detects it, but it can't detect and correct `/` in all cases automatically.

**awk** is from *nix and gives a backslash a completely different meaning as Windows command processor. I have no experience with **awk**, but I think it is better to specify file names with paths passed as arguments to **awk** also on Windows with a forward slash as directory separator instead of a backslash. Therefore I suggest to replace the lines:

```
SET awk="tools/3rdparty/bin/awk.exe"
SET grep="tools/3rdparty/bin/grep.exe"

rem Other lines of your batch file.

%grep% "Test net output #0" auxx.txt | %awk% "{print %11}" > aux1.txt
%grep% "Test net output #1" auxx.txt | %awk% "{print %11}" > aux2.txt
```

by

```
set "awk=tools\3rdparty\bin\awk.exe"
set "grep=tools\3rdparty\bin\grep.exe"

rem Other lines of your batch file.

set "LogFileName=%~11"
set "LogFileName=%LogFileName:\=/%"
"%grep%" "Test net output #0" auxx.txt | "%awk%" "{print %LogFileName%}" > aux1.txt
"%grep%" "Test net output #1" auxx.txt | "%awk%" "{print %LogFileName%}" > aux2.txt
```

Using *nix tools on Windows requires thinking on what is interpreted by Windows native command line tools like `cmd.exe` and what is interpreted by the *nix tools like `awk.exe` and `grep.exe` to use correct syntax on arguments.

`set "LogFileName=%LogFileName:\=/%"` replaces all backslashes by forward slashes in log file name with relative path. Run in a command prompt window `set /?` and read all output help pages for details about string replacements / substitutions in values of environment variables.

And on line

```
%paste% aux0.txt aux3.txt aux1.txt aux2.txt | column -t >> %LOG%.train
```

the Windows command processor (`cmd.exe`) can't find an application `column` with a file extension defined in environment variable `PATHEXT` in current directory or any directory defined in environment variable `PATH`. This application must be also specified with file extension and (relative) path.