# What is the step-by-step approach to solving: 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java, windows, maven, batch-file

I'm a rookie when it comes to Windows. I have installed Apache Maven by following the instructions in the given read me.

What I did was unzip the download and then `set PATH="c:\program files\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin"`

I then typed `mvn --version` into the command prompt and then I got the error; `'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`.

I have read various answers to this problem. Many people have solved it by moving the `M2` and `M2_HOME` from user variables to system variables.

The problem is that I am getting confused by this. Can someone provide me with  step-by-step instructions on how to solve this?

Comment: Does `c:\program files\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\mvn --version` work?

Comment: The step-by-step contains only 1 step: make sure the script `mvn.bat` is in the PATH... Check your environment variables and set it there.

Comment: Looks like you forgot the closing quotes. Or is it just a copy & paste error?

Comment: I feel the need to point out that you should be setting PATH like `set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin"` since otherwise you're overwriting the entire PATH variable and you do _not_ want to be doing that. (Note that this will almost certainly not solve the problem you're currently having, but it will prevent other problems down the line.)

Comment: Don't use `M2_HOME` or `M2` not needed. Only correct entry in `PATH` is needed. And of course JAVA_HOME.

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ It does't work. When I do it I get the error message saying that `mvn` is recognized.

Comment: @Tunaki I went into `Control Panel -> System -> Environment Variables - > System Variables`. I looked at what is there and I can see "Path" not "PATH". Currently "Path" has the value of `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\mvn.bat`. I added the `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\mvn.bat` at the end and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @Frank That was a copy & paste error. I actually used `set` without the quotation marks. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @TheRealRave You missed the quotes in your System variables. It should be `"C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin"`

Comment: Don't specify paths in __PATH__ with double quotes even if the path contains 1 or more spaces. That is not common. A folder path in __PATH__ must be specified with double quotes only if the folder path contains a semicolon (CSV standard with semicolon as separator). See also [How to set environment variables with spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564)

Comment: @Mofi, I agree, double-quotes are not common in `PATH`; but they do not harm, do they?

Comment: @aschipfl Windows itself removes the double quotes around a folder path in __PATH__ and therefore has no problems with folder paths with surrounding double quotes. But I have seen other applications (mainly installers/uninstallers) which modify __PATH__ and have problems with double quoted folder paths in __PATH__ resulting in corrupting __PATH__ value. For example the resulting __PATH__ value has an odd number of double quotes causing misinterpretation of the folder paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Unzip maven `apache-maven-3.3.3-bin.zip` to a location on system say `C:\Program Files`. So we have a directory structure as:

[image]

Step 2: Set an environment variable (system variable) M2_HOME=C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.3

[image]

Step 3: Edit the PATH variable (system variable) of your system. Add `%M2_HOME%\bin;` at the beginning of your `PATH` variable and click `OK`.

[image]

Step 4: Run `mvn -version` from command prompt.

[image]

Hope, this helps.

Comment: This worked. Thank you. One mistake I was doing is that I was using `apache-maven-3.3.9-bin` instead of `apache-maven-3.3.9-bin`