# Set /a variable and variable becomes 0 missing operator

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a game and for `set /a "var"`, `var` becomes 0 and missing operator too.

> This is a bit of code

```
set /p confirm=y/n : 
if '%confirm%' == 'y' (
set /a partner=Ignite
set /a monsterlevel=5
set /a reqexp=100
set /a currentexp=0
set /a element=Fire
set /a evolution=Igneous
set /a move1=Scratch
set /a move2=Burn
set /a move3=Flame Spread
set /a move4=Quick Slash
set /a hp=100
goto mymonster
)
if '%confirm%' == 'n' goto pick
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: why do you use `/a`?  `set /a partner=Ignite` sets `%partner%` to the value of `%Ignite%`, which is empty. `set /a move3=Flame Spread` tries to set `%move3%` to `%flame% [missing operator here] %Spread%`.

Comment: Isn't `/a` for arithmetic use? Meaning that leaving the `/a` out should solve the problem or not? `set /?` tells you that the argument has to be a numeric value which is not the case.

Comment: What do you mean by "missing operator too"? Is that an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a command prompt window, run `set /?` and read all help pages output into the console window.

The option `/A` is for arithmetic expressions and should be never used to assign a string value to an environment variable. Environment variables are always of type string.

On the line

```
set /a partner=Ignite
```

the Windows command processor interprets `Ignite` as name of an environment variable which string value converted to an integer value should be assigned to variable `partner` converted back from integer to string. As there is most likely no variable `Ignite` the value 0 is assigned to `partner` as string.

On the line

```
set /a move3=Flame Spread
```

the Windows command processor interprets `Flame` and `Spread` as name of environment variables. But there is no operator between and therefore the arithmetic expression is invalid because of the missing operator.

The solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "confirm=n"
set /P "confirm=y/n : "
if /I "!confirm!" == "y" (
    set "partner=Ignite"
    set "monsterlevel=5"
    set "reqexp=100"
    set "currentexp=0"
    set "element=Fire"
    set "evolution=Igneous"
    set "move1=Scratch"
    set "move2=Burn"
    set "move3=Flame Spread"
    set "move4=Quick Slash"
    set "hp=100"
    goto mymonster
)
if /I "!confirm!" == "n" goto pick
rem The user has entered whether y/Y nor n/N. What to do now?
```

The environment variable `confirm` is defined with a default value in case of batch user just hits <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> without entering anything at all. In this case the environment variable `confirm` keeps its current value or is still undefined if not defined before.

The string comparison is done case-insensitive because of **IF** option `/I`. Run in a command prompt window `if /?` for help on this command .

And the string comparison is done with using delayed expansion. This is for security as the batch user could enter by mistake or intentionally for example `"<` and making the string comparison now without using delayed expansion the batch processing would immediately exit on first **IF** condition line because of a syntax error.

Always use double quotes and not single quotes on comparing strings. Double quotes have a special meaning for Windows command processor on evaluating an **IF** condition, but single quotes don't. The character `'` is interpreted on a string comparison with `==` like a letter or a digit, it has no special meaning. But please note that the Windows command processor compares the strings left and right of `==` with including the double quotes. So not the strings inside the double quotes are compared, but the strings with the double quotes which means `if /I "!confirm!" == y` would be never true.

See also the answer on [How to set environment variables with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564)