# How can I automate the installation of a program that has issues with finding the Java vm?

Tags: cmd, path

On Windows 8.1 I am installing a program which looks for the Java vm location.

It runs without any problem with these environment variables set manually:

```
JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_102"
PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

It does NOT run with this:

```
JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_102"
PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
```

Where I have written `%PATH%` above means all other necessary system paths separated with semicolons etc.

The program can only find the jvm when `PATH` is a single directory entry.

I have tried running the program from a batch file and temporarily changing the `PATH`. I understand that the temporary change only exists while that command screen is open.

This is my batch file:

```
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin
start Epson_JavaPOS_1.1.4 blah blah.exe
cmd /K
```

Problem is I think the temp value is not being retained when the program installation starts and user input is detected.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_102\Epson_JavaPOS_1.1.4 blah blah.exe"` You just run programs directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mofi - I found your information extremely helpful and so led me in the right direction. Here is the solution to my question of how i can automate the installation of the program that cant find the Java vm...

1. Delete this environment variable entirely - JAVA_HOME
2. Edit PATH environment variable - Remove %JAVA_HOME%\bin
3. Amend batch script

The program WILL find the jvm when the jvm path is APPENDED to %PATH% instead of PREPENDED.

Batch script amendment:

Example 1

```
setx JAVA_HOME "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Java\jre1.8.0_102"
setx PATH "%JAVA_HOME%\bin"
start Epson_JavaPOS_ADK_1141.exe
cmd /K
```

**OR THIS** (as Mofi suggested)

Example 2

```
set "JAVA_HOME=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Java\jre1.8.0_102"
if "%PATH:~-1%" == ";" (
    set "PATH=%PATH%%JAVA_HOME%\bin"
) else (
    set "PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin"
)
start Epson_JavaPOS_ADK_1141.exe
cmd /K
```

In Example 2, %JAVA_HOME%\bin is appended to PATH variable twice.

In Example 1:

This line:

```
 setx JAVA_HOME "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Java\jre1.8.0_102"
```

creates a User variable which overrides any System variable.(In my case, none)

This line:

```
setx PATH "%JAVA_HOME%\bin"
```

creates a User variable which appends to PATH System variable.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the answers on

- [How to set environment variables with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564)
- [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)

for an explanation why `set variable="string with space"` is most often not good like here with variable value **with** the double quotes being concatenated next with another string.

The first script code in question **would produce** on expansion the `PATH` variable with value:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_102"\bin
```

which is definitely not right.

But it does not even produce this string as the command `set` is also missing in both lines. For that reason Windows command processor outputs on execution of the first line just an error message as it can't find an application, script or internal command with name `JAVA_HOME`. The second line does not result in an error message because of command **PATH** resulting in local environment variable `PATH` being redefined with value `\bin`.

Use this code to **append** the path to *Java* home directory to `PATH`:

```
set "JAVA_HOME=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Java\jre1.8.0_102"
if "%PATH:~-1%" == ";" (
    set "PATH=%PATH%%JAVA_HOME%\bin"
) else (
    set "PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin"
)
```

Use this code to **prepend** the path to *Java* home directory to `PATH`:

```
set "JAVA_HOME=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Java\jre1.8.0_102"
set "PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%"
```

The semicolon separated directory paths within string value of environment variable `PATH` are not double quoted even when a directory path contains 1 or more spaces or parentheses.

There is only one exception on which a directory path must be added to `PATH` with double quotes: the directory path contains itself 1 or even more semicolons.

Run in a command prompt window `set /?` or `help set` for help on command **SET**.