# Batch file command to select newest folder except if specific name

Tags: batch-file

We have a batch file to create a variable from the folder name of the newest folder created in a specific location. As newer versions of this software is released the version number (folder name also) i.e. 10.0, 10.1, 10.2, 10.3 folder is created in this directory. Until now this has worked without hitch, however in the last update they decided to add a folder called `Install` in this same directory.

Is it possible to change the following script to ignore the `Install` folder and select the newest created folder name instead:

```
SET TABVER="C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau Server\"
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir %TABVER% /b /ad-h /t:c /od') DO SET VERSION=%%i
SET TABCMD="C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau Server\%VERSION%\bin\tabcmd.exe"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This batch code could be used:

```
set "TABVER=C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau Server\"
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%TABVER%" /B /AD-H /T:C /O-D 2^>nul') do if /I not "%%I" == "Install" set "VERSION=%%I" & goto FoundVersion

echo Error: There is no version subfolder in probably not already existing folder:
echo/
echo        %TABVER%
echo/
pause
goto :EOF

:FoundVersion
set TABCMD="%TABVER%%VERSION%\bin\tabcmd.exe"
rem Other commands using TABCMD
```

The **DIR** option `/od` is modified to `/O-D` to get the list of subdirectories in reverse order output by command **DIR** with newest directory first and oldest directory last.

The additional **IF** command compares case-insensitive the current directory name with the string `Install`. Only if the directory name is **not** `Install` the directory name is assigned to environment variable `VERSION` and the loop is exited without processing all other directory names with a jump to label `FoundVersion`.

I added an error output in case of `C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau Server` does not exist at all, contains no subdirectories or contains just `Install` and with halting batch file execution until user presses any key and then exiting the batch file processing.

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

See also [How to set environment variables with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564) In general it is better to use the command line `set "variable=value"` and reference the environment variable with `"%variable%"` instead of using `set variable="value"` and reference the environment variable with just `%variable%`. Look on `%TABVER%` references why it makes sense not having assigned a folder path with the double quotes to an environment variable.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`

Read also [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) and [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)

Comment: Many thanks for the info Mofi it is much appreciated. I can confirm also this has worked perfectly.