# Windows CMD : Loop FOR with file containing space in his path

Tags: windows, for-loop, cmd, path, filesize

I'm trying to retrieve the size of two files to compare the size of eachothers.
The problem is, one of the two files contain a space in his path, the code is like that :

```
SET pathToFile1="C:\Program Files\file1ToCompare"
SET pathToFile2="C:\Users\file2ToCompare"

FOR /F "usebackq" %%A ('%pathToFile1%') DO SET file1Size=%%~zA
FOR /F "usebackq" %%B ('%pathToFile2%') DO SET file2Size=%%~zB

IF %file1Size% LSS %file2Size% (
    :: do things
)
```

The size of the second file is correctly set, but the size of the first file is not retrieved... I've been searching an answer for a day now, but can't find any one (maybe i'm not searching correctly, sorry in this case)

Do you have an idea to get the size of the first file ?

Comment: `FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in (…` see https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use option `/F` which is for parsing one or more strings read from a file or specified directly or read from captured output of a command executed in a separate command process in background.

Use just command **FOR** without any option to process the specified file.

```
SET "pathToFile1=C:\Program Files\file1ToCompare"
SET "pathToFile2=C:\Users\file2ToCompare"

IF NOT EXIST "%pathToFile1%" GOTO :EOF
IF NOT EXIST "%pathToFile2%" GOTO :EOF

FOR %%A IN ("%pathToFile1%") DO SET "file1Size=%%~zA"
FOR %%B IN ("%pathToFile2%") DO SET "file2Size=%%~zB"

IF %file1Size% LSS %file2Size% (
    rem do things
)
```

Read answer on [How to set environment variables with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564) why it is better to use the syntax `set "variable=value"` and enclose the entire string including one or more environment variable references in double quotes.

Read next answer on [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564) The two **IF** commands are necessary as `SET "file1Size=%%~zA"` results in `SET "file1Size="` on first file not existing which means the environment variable `file1Size` is not defined respectively deleted after the **FOR** command line.

The **IF** condition comparing the two file sizes would result in an exit of batch file processing because of a syntax error if either `file1Size` or `file2Size` does not exist on reaching this command line.

Please note that Windows command interpreter can handle only file sizes less than 2 [GiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte) in the **IF** condition.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`