# Variable %ProgramFiles(x86)% not set or returned as expected from batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables

Given the following batch file:

```
@echo off
echo %programfiles(x86)%
set test=%programfiles(x86)%
echo %test%
if 0==0 ( 
    set test2=%programfiles(x86)%
)
echo %test2%
```

the output is returned as:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)
C:\Program Files (x86)
C:\Program Files (x86
```

Notice the missing bracket on the last line.

Can anyone explain what has happened or what I've done incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `%programfiles(x86)%` is expanded, it becomes `C:\Program Files (x86)`

Your if command becomes

```
if 0==0 (
    set test2=C:\Program Files (x86)
)
```

The parser then reads it as

```
if 0==0 (
    set test2=C:\Program Files (x86
)
```

This can be prevented with

```
if 0==0 (
    set "test2=%programfiles(x86)%"
)
```

The "" delimiters ensure that the exact string is passed as an argument to the SET command.

Input of a single ) on a line produces no error response in the CMD environment.

Comment: OMG. I feel so dumb. Thank you very much for the fast solution!

Answer (score 1):

`%programfiles(x86)%` was parsed to be `C:\Program Files (x86)` which caused closure of your if statement (The last character of the path is `)`, which closed the if)

You can try adding quotation marks to indicate its a part of the string:

```
if 0==0 ( 
    set "test2=%programfiles(x86)%"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for missing closing parenthesis `)` can be seen on modifying `@echo off` to `@echo ON` and running this batch file from within a command prompt window.

The command line with the **IF** condition and the entire command block starting with `(` is preprocessed before executing the **IF** command at all to following single command line:

```
if 0 == 0 (set test2=C:\Program Files (x86 )
```

Windows command interpreter found after replacing `%programfiles(x86)%` by `C:\Program Files (x86)` during the preprocessing phase the closing parenthesis `)` not inside a double quoted string. So for Windows command interpreter `)` in `C:\Program Files (x86)` not enclosed in a double quoted string marks end of command block. The additional `)` without a matching `(` is simply ignored. The result is that `test2` gets assigned only `C:\Program Files (x86`.

The solution is enclosing argument of command **SET** in double quotes as explained in answers on [How to set environment variables with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564) and [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)

```
@echo off
echo %ProgramFiles(x86)%
set "test=%ProgramFiles(x86)%"
echo %test%
if 0 == 0 ( 
    set "test2=%ProgramFiles(x86)%"
)
echo %test2%
```