# Backup script - find file by pattern, read it's full name and pass to script

Tags: windows, cmd, scripting, backup

I'm trying to use *7-Zip* for backup purposes.
I have already wrote script for full backup:

```
@echo off
set source="c:\Source"
set destination="C:\Dest"
set dd=%DATE:~0,2%
set mm=%DATE:~3,2%
set yyyy=%DATE:~6,4%
set curdate=%dd%-%mm%-%yyyy%
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip -ssw -mx6 -r0 %destination%\Full_%curdate%.zip %source%
```

The new script intended for incremental backup is started after the full backup is made. But I don't really get how to make my second script to read files from directory and look for the file staring like `full_xx_xx_xxxx.zip` and assign its filename to a variable and then pass it to the script for incremental backup.

I tried script below, but it's not working:

```
@echo off
set source="c:\Source"
set destination="c:\Dest"
set exten="Full_*.zip"
set passwd="NAS"
set dd=%DATE:~0,2%
set mm=%DATE:~3,2%
set yyyy=%DATE:~6,4%
set curdate=%dd%-%mm%-%yyyy%
for %%a in %exten do echo %%a
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" u -tzip -ssw -r0 %destination%\%%a.zip -u- -up0q3x2z0!"%destination%\diff_%date%.zip" %source%
```

Comment: Can you say something more about "it's not working(?" In what way is it not working? Are there any error messages? Is the new archive file created?

Comment: It doesn't make a desired incremental backup file. And reports "unexpected appearance: a". The incremental backup (nor any other files) don't appear at the destination folder. I'm stuck(

Comment: The mention of `%exten` should have a closing percent. `%exten%` Probably need to be in parentheses also.

Comment: Your last line uses the for variable `%%a` without being in the scope `=same line or (code block)` of the previous for command (in addition to @lit's hints) .

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple mistakes in both scripts.

I recommend reading first [How to set environment variables with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564) and [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564). The syntax `set variable="value in quotes"` is often not good because it assigns the string `"value in quotes"` **with** the double quotes and all trailing spaces/tabs which might exist also in batch file to the environment variable with name `variable`. This syntax is problematic on concatenating the string value of the environment variable with other strings as done in posted code with `%destination%` because of the `"` being now somewhere in middle of the final argument string instead of enclosing the entire argument string. Better is the syntax `set "variable=value without or with spaces"` with `"` left to variable name because of the double quotes are interpreted now as argument string separators and perhaps existing spaces/tabs on line after second `"` are ignored by Windows command processor.

The usage of dynamic environment variable `DATE` makes it possible to quickly get current **locale** date in a format usable for file/folder names. But it must be taken into account that the date format of value of `DATE` depends on region/country/locale set for the user account which is used on running the batch file. I suppose that `echo %DATE%` results in an output of a date in format `DD.MM.YYYY` and so the command lines using `DATE` are correct for you with your user account according to the configured country.

The **FOR** command line is completely wrong and results in an exit of batch file execution with an error message output by `cmd.exe` interpreting the batch file line by line. This error output can be seen on running the batch file from within a command prompt window instead of double clicking on the batch file. See [debugging a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564) for details on how to debug a batch file to find syntax errors like this reported by Windows command processor during execution of a batch file.

So I suggest for the first batch file:

```
@echo off
set "Source=C:\Source"
set "Destination=C:\Dest"
set "CurrentDate=%DATE:~6,4%-%DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~0,2%"
"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip -ssw -mx6 -r0 "%Destination%\Full_%CurrentDate%.zip" "%Source%"
```

The current **locale** date is assigned to the environment variable `CurrentDate` in format `YYYY-MM-DD` instead of `DD-MM-YYYY`. The date format `YYYY-MM-DD` is the international date format according to ISO 8601. It has one big advantage in comparison to all [locale date formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country) in file names: The file names with date in format `YYYY-MM-DD` sorted alphabetically as usual are at the same time sorted chronological. That makes it much easier for people and scripts finding a specific file in a list of file names with date in file name.

I am not really sure what you want to do with the second batch file. So I can only suppose what you want to do and suggest for the second batch file:

```
@echo off
set "Source=C:\Source"
set "Destination=C:\Dest"
set "CurrentDate=%DATE:~6,4%-%DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~0,2%"
set "NamePattern=Full_*.zip"
for /F "skip=1 eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%Destination%\%NamePattern%" /A-D /B /O-N 2^>nul') do (
    "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" u -tzip -ssw -r0 "%Destination%\%%I" -u- -up0q3x2z0!"%Destination%\Diff_%CurrentDate%.zip" "%Source%"
    goto Done
)
:Done
```

The **FOR** loop runs command **DIR** with using a separate command process started in background to get the list of `Full_*.zip` file names in destination directory sorted reverse by name which means the full backup ZIP file created today before with first batch file is at top on using date format `YYYY-MM-DD` and the previously created ZIP file from yesterday (or whenever the last but one full ZIP file was created) is output as second line.

**FOR** skips the first line with ZIP file name with current date and runs *7-Zip* with previously created ZIP file (yesterday) to create the difference ZIP file. Then the **FOR** loop is exited without processing all other full ZIP files with a jump to the label below the **FOR** loop.

Both batch files together:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "Source=C:\Source"
set "Destination=C:\Dest"
set "CurrentDate=%DATE:~6,4%-%DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~0,2%"
set "NamePattern=Full_*.zip"
rem Create full ZIP backup.
"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip -ssw -mx6 -r0 "%Destination%\Full_%CurrentDate%.zip" "%Source%"
rem Create difference ZIP backup with files added/changed in source directory
rem in comparison to the files compressed into last but on full ZIP backup.
for /F "skip=1 eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%Destination%\%NamePattern%" /A-D /B /O-N 2^>nul') do (
    "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" u -tzip -ssw -r0 "%Destination%\%%I" -u- -up0q3x2z0!"%Destination%\Diff_%CurrentDate%.zip" "%Source%"
    goto Done
)
:Done
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`