# In batch, how to add spaces to variables?

Tags: batch-file

I am creating a game. The character moves when the player presses A or D. My question that I have: How to add spaces to these variables in batch? I have this code that set blank variables for the player and the enemy:

```
set right=
set left=
set leften=
set righten=
```

Comment: [How to set environment variables with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564)

Comment: If there is a _space_ right to the `=` then it is assigned to the variable; let me recommend to set quotes like `set "var= "` to make the _spaces_ visible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set "right= "
```

Always a good idea to use quotes in `set` string-commands.

Demo using advanced techniques...

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

:: a variable with many spaces

SET "spaces=                    "

SET "myvar="
ECHO Hello%myvar%World

CALL :addspaces myvar 2

ECHO Hello%myvar%World

CALL :addspaces myvar 3

ECHO Hello%myvar%World

SET "mynewvar=Another"

ECHO %mynewvar%Spaces

CALL :addspaces mynewvar 3

ECHO %mynewvar%Spaces

ECHO ----------------Another method --------

SET "myvar="
ECHO Another%myvar%method

CALL :addchars myvar 2

ECHO Another%myvar%method

CALL :addchars myvar 3 x

ECHO Another%myvar%method

SET "mynewvar=Batch is "

ECHO %mynewvar%easy

CALL :addchars mynewvar 13 "so "

ECHO %mynewvar%easy

PAUSE
GOTO :eof

:: To variable name %1, add %2 spaces

:addspaces
CALL SET "%1=%%%1%%%%spaces:~-%2%%"
GOTO :eof

:: To variable name %1, add %2 of %3;spaces if %3 is missing

:addchars

FOR /L %%Z IN (1,1,%2) DO IF "%~3"=="" (CALL SET "%1=%%%1%% ") ELSE (CALL SET "%1=%%%1%%%~3")

GOTO :eof
```

The two subroutines require explanation.

Because of the way `cmd` operates, in the `:addspaces` routine, the `set` is `CALL`ed and the following substitutions are made before execution - reading left-to-right

> set "%1=%%%1%%%%spaces:~-%2%%"

first, substitute the parameter values for %1..%9

> set "`parameter1`=%%`parameter1`%%%%spaces:~-`parameter2`%%"

Next, observe escape-sequences, `%` escapes `%`

> set "parameter1=`%`parameter1`%%`spaces:~-parameter2`%`"

When this command is executed, it's re-parsed as

set "parameter1=*contents of parameter1*%spaces:~*contents of**parameter2*%"

The second routine is another approach, same parsing trick used but this time adding the third parameter which may be a character or a string and if the string to be repeated contains a separator character like a space, then it must be `"quoted"`.

Comment: If I have a variable with a space in it, is there a command to add another space next to it?

Comment: @BrickMan: `set "var=%var% "`