# Create Directory and sub directories crashing

Tags: windows, batch-file

The script takes user inputs then crashes

Tried renaming files and variables, and combining variables.

```
cls
set /p FN="First Name: "
set /p LN="SECOND Name: "
set folder="%FN% %LN%"
set path="F:\ADMIN\USERS\_USER"
set final = %path%\%folder%
if not exist %final% (
    mkdir %path%\%folder%
    mkdir %path%\%folder%\Info
    mkdir %path%\%folder%\JOB
    mkdir %path%\%folder%\HR
    mkdir %path%\%folder%\Department
    copy %path%\%folder%\_takeoff.xlsx %path%\%folder%
) else (
    echo %path%\%folder% + " is already Created"
)
pause
```

Script crashes

EDIT: Here is the updated code. I creates the intended files in the intended location. However it also creates the files on the Desktop. Not sure if editing here is what I should to do or ask a new question.

```
echo off
cls
echo Type The SO number, Customer, and Job named when asked. Then press Enter
echo.
set /p SO="SO #: "
set /p Customer="Customer Name: "
set /p JOB="Job Name: "
set folder="%SO%"_"%Customer%"_"%JOB%"
echo %folder%
set dir="F:\Sales\SALES FOLDER\_QUOTES"
set final="%dir%\%folder%"
set dst="%final%/1 - Estimating Orginal Quote Material"
if not exist %final% (
    mkdir "%dst%"
    copy /-Y "%dir%\_takeoff.xlsx" %est%
    mkdir "%dst%\Downloads"
    mkdir "%dst%\Plans"
    mkdir "%dst%\Quotes"
    mkdir "%dst%\Cut Sheets"
    mkdir "%dst%\Venders"
    mkdir "%final%\2 - Signed Quote - Contract\Non-Current Purchase Orders"
    mkdir "%final%\3 - Special Purchase Trading Goods"
    mkdir "%final%\4 - Engineering\2 - Submittals"
    mkdir "%final%\4 - Engineering\3 - Approvals"
    mkdir "%final%\4 - Engineering\4 - Drawings in Progress\Released Production Drawings"
    mkdir "%final%\5 - Final Production Drawings"
    mkdir "%final%\6 - Q.C. Document"
    mkdir "%final%\7 - Project Management _ Schedule"   
) 
pause
```

Comment: Your code does not make sense! If `"F:\ADMIN\USERS\_USER\FirstName Surname"` doesn't exist, i.e.`If Not Exist "%final%\"` it is not possible within that block to `Copy "F:\ADMIN\USERS\_USER\FirstName Surname\_takeoff.xlsx"` to `"F:\ADMIN\USERS\_USER\FirstName Surname"`, because you've just created `"F:\ADMIN\USERS\_USER\FirstName Surname"` and it has no content, i.e. `_takeoff.xlsx` is not located in the newly created directory yet!

Comment: @Compo, You are correct the copy path is meant to be %path%\_takeoff.xls. Got a little copy paste happy when making it

Comment: I recommend reading [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) as well as [How to set environment variables with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564) and [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) and finally [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564)

Comment: By the way, the script does not crash. Executables can crash, but not scripts processed by a script interpreter (executable) like `cmd.exe` in this case. See [debugging a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564) on how to solve such simple syntax errors by yourself next time. Windows command processor outputs an error message with information about cause of __exit__ (not crash) of script processing because of a serious syntax error making it impossible to continue processing of the batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the spaces you have on the `set final = %path%\%folder%` line; if you take those extra spaces out you should be fine.

To take it a step further I highly recommend adding quotes to places that don't have them, and moving them ahead of the variables in your `set` statements to account for any spaces users may add:

```
cls
set /p "FN=First Name: "
set /p "LN=SECOND Name: "
set "folder=%FN% %LN%"
set "mypath=F:\ADMIN\USERS\_USER"
set "final=%mypath%\%folder%"
if not exist "%final%" (
    mkdir "%final%"
    mkdir "%final%\Info"
    mkdir "%final%\JOB"
    mkdir "%final%\HR"
    mkdir "%final%\Department"
    copy "%mypath%\_takeoff.xlsx" "%final%"
) else (
    echo %final% is already Created
)
pause
```

You also don't need the quotes in your echo, unless you just want it to echo quotes.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler looking idea:

```bat
PushD "F:\ADMIN\USERS\_USER" 2>NUL || Exit /B
ClS
Set "FN="
Set /P "FN=First Name: "
Set "LN="
Set /P "LN=Surname: "
Rem Note: You should perform some input verification here.

MD "%FN% %LN%" "%FN% %LN%\Info" "%FN% %LN%\JOB" "%FN% %LN%\HR" "%FN% %LN%%\Department" 2>NUL
If Not Exist "%FN% %LN%\_takeoff.xlsx" Copy "_takeoff.xlsx" "%FN% %LN%"
```

Please take note of the `Rem`arked line, *you currently have no control over what the end user enters at each prompt, they can enter nothing or anything, (including invalid characters)!*