# How to extract, using cmd, string between quotes from a particular line

Tags: batch-file

Hope I will be clear with my problem and what I search for. I have a long script in a .sjs file (basically txt with different extension), part of which are the following lines. In the comments below this is either referred to as input.txt or Builder.sjs

```
var Want_spring_aid_file_update = 0;
var Front_spring_aid_file = "name_1.pspck";
var Rear_spring_aid_file = "name_2.pspck";
```

I have been looking around for a .bat script that can probe certain lines, 2 and 3 in the case above, in this .sjs file and write the string between double quotes in a text new file. In the comments below this new text file is referred to as comments.txt.

I have found on this marvelous website a script that outputs all the strings between quotes in that file. I want just on particular lines. The script I am talking about is below.

```
>"output.txt" (
 for /f usebackq^ tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%A in ("input.txt") do echo "%%A" 
)
```

Also It would be helpful is someone could help me understand the role of certain characters in the above script. These are ^, 2^, ^=^.

Thanks guys !

Comment: Instead of using `"input.txt"` why not use `'FindStr [options] [search mask] "input.txt"'` to just pick out the data related to your required `var` names?

Comment: This do the trick with the shown data: `for /F "skip=1 tokens=4 delims=; " %%a in (test.txt) do echo %%~a`. The `skip=1` part omits line 1. `"tokens=4 delims=; "` takes the 4th token delimited by spaces or semicolon. The inclusion of a tilde in `%%~a` part show such a token removing enclosing quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Compo thanks! The following code did it after a bit of trial and error.

```
@echo off
>>"comments.txt" ( 
    for /f usebackq^ tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%A in ( 'findstr /C:var Front_spring_aid_file = ^"part_name1^"; "Builder.sjs"') do echo %%A
)
```

Comment: The `findstr` command line results in searching for the string `var` in the files `Front_spring_aid_file`, `=`, `part_name1;` and `Builder.sjs`. To find the line with variable `Front_spring_aid_file` it is necessary to use for example `findstr /C:"var Front_spring_aid_file =" "Builder.sjs"` because this results in searching in file `Builder.sjs` for a line containing the string `var Front_spring_aid_file =`.

Comment: To search for a line containing the string `var Front_spring_aid_file = "part_name1";` it is necessary to use the command line `findstr /L /C:"var Front_spring_aid_file = \"part_name1\";" "Builder.sjs"`. But I doubt if it makes sense to search for more or less an entire line as in this case the output of `findstr` is the same as the search string. Better would be using a regular expression as with `findstr /R /C:"var  *Front_spring_aid_file *=  *\"..*\";" "Builder.sjs"`. Run `findstr /?` in a command prompt window for help on this regular expression search.

Comment: @Mofi . Complicated stuff indeed. It does work and I believe it works because the switch `/C:` tells the `findstr` function to ignore the spaces in the string that follows and thus it goes up tot he next `"` without an escape in front of it, in this case this being the " in front of `"Builder.sjs"`. If I write it as `'findstr /C:"var Front_spring_aid_file = ^"part_name1^";" "Builder.sjs"'` it says the sintax is incorrect. BTW thanks for noticing my small part name leak.

Comment: @Mofi If i replace the `findstr` in mine with the one you suggested which includes the switch `/L` the output is var Front_spring_aid_file = \

Comment: No, `/C:"search string with spaces"` must be used to search for a literal string containing also spaces. Try it out with running just the `findstr` command line in a command prompt window in directory containing the file `Builder.sjs` as I have done too. You just think it works as expected because __FOR__ filters the wrong output of __FINDSTR__ to the expected output. The escape character in a search string of __FINDSTR__ is ``\``. But this enables by default a regular expression search which is the reason why `/L` must be also specified to explicitly request a literal search.

Comment: @Mofi Apparently the code I posted works even if you don't use the escapes `^` in front of the `"` in the string to be searched for. Now that is weird.

Comment: The opposite is using the option `/R` to instruct __FINDSTR__ that the search string is a regular expression string and therefore a regular expression search should be used. We could safe both our time if you edit your question and explain with a better example what you want to search for in `Builder.sjs` respectively `input.txt`, which lines should be found by the search string and what should be finally written into the output file from the found lines.

Comment: You need to learn that each application interprets the argument strings on command line different. There is no general rule used by `cmd.exe` and `findstr.exe` and all other console applications how to interpret the rest of the line after command or executable name. I demonstrated and explained that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24008269/3074564) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564). You are confused because you think what works for `for` interpreted by `cmd.exe` works also for `findstr.exe`, but that is not true. Run `findstr /?` and read about `^`.

Comment: @Mofi Thanks for the help and for the references. I believe you and I will look into it later this evening (it 11 AM now where I am) as I want to understand things properly but for the moment for some reason that works and I have to crack on with what I have to do at work. Once I understand things I am sure I will come back with some more questions. I would be very grateful for you guidance when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

The command **FOR** with option `/F` is used to process lines of a file, or a single string specified in double quotes, or output of a command line executed by **FOR** in a separate command process in background captured from handle **STDOUT** of this background command process.

The first option `usebackq` results in interpreting the file name specified in double quotes not as string to process, but as double quoted name of a file of which lines should be processed by **FOR**.

The option `delims=` is used to specify the delimiters for splitting each non empty line not starting with default end of line character `;` up into one or more substrings called tokens. The default delimiters are space and horizontal tab character. `delims=` without any character means do not split up the line at all. Only the double quote character `"` should be used for this task as delimiter.

The option `tokens=` defines which substring(s) should be assigned to the loop variable(s). By default only the first substring (token) is assigned to the specified loop variable. By specifying `tokens=2` the command **FOR** is informed that of interest is the second substring which should be assigned to the specified loop variable (first). This means also if a line does not have a string after 1 or more of the specified delimiters, the line is also ignored. This is true for the first line of `input.txt` which does not contain a double quote character at all.

Run in a command prompt window `for /?` for more information about the options of command **FOR** output on several pages.

Those options of **FOR** are specified usually enclosed in double quotes.

```
>"output.txt" (
    for /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims="" %%A in ("input.txt") do echo "%%A" 
)
```

But the problem here is specifying `"` as delimiter. For Windows command interpreter the option string is `"usebackq tokens=2 delims="` which would not make much sense because that means the lines should not be split up into tokens and nevertheless only the second token is of interest. However, the next `"` is invalid because expected next is the loop variable, a single character with a percent sign before. The percent sign must be escaped in a batch file with an additional percent sign.

For that reason it is necessary to specify the options of **FOR** without enclosing them in double quotes. So it must be made sure during the preprocessing phase of Windows command interpreter before executing the **FOR** command line that the 3 options are interpreted as a single argument string.

The escape character to use in batch files is the caret character `^` which instructs Windows command interpreter to interpret the next character as literal character belonging to an argument string. Only `%` must be escaped with `%` instead of `^` to be interpreted as literal character.

It can be read on running in a command prompt window `cmd /?` on last paragraph on last output help page which characters in directory/file names (or other argument strings) require enclosing the string in double quotes: the space character, the characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` and not mentioned by help the characters `"|<>` which can't be used in a directory/file name.

So it is specified with `usebackq^ tokens^=2^ delims^=^"` for Windows command interpreter that an argument string not enclosed in double quotes with the unusual text `usebackq tokens=2 delims="` should be passed to command **FOR** as second argument after `/F`.

Windows command interpreter interprets a space character and an equal sign not escaped with `^` as delimiter between argument strings.

A double quote not escaped with `^` is interpreted as begin of an argument string which ends with another double quote and all characters between with exception of `%` and `!` when delayed expansion is enabled are interpreted as literal characters.

That is the reason why the spaces characters, the equal signs and the double quote must be escaped with `^` in the argument string `usebackq tokens=2 delims="`.

See [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/) for more detailed information about command line parsing by Windows command interpreter.

Comment: Hi Mofi! Thanks a lot for the clarification. I am now clear on what "^" does but am still a bit in doubt about its position.As in why is appears after the the number 2 and before a space.
This however did now say how to solve my problem. However the solution mentioned by @Compo worked after a bit of trial and error